# How much damage do the Abomination's claws and teeth do?

Tags: damage, wfrp-2e, wfrp

I've just started playing the second edition of Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay and I absolutely love it.

However, I just read through Forges of Nuln, and I saw that the Abomination has its weapons as "Claws and teeth".

Logically, the Abomination wouldn't deal the same amount of damage as Skaven or other creatures with the same weapons.

So how much damage do claws and teeth do in general, and how much for the Abomination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The abomination  has the **Natural Weapons** ability, which states:

> You have claws or vicious teeth that can rend apart
>   your foes in combat. When attacking without a weapon, **you
>   count as being armed with a hand weapon**. You cannot parry
>   with your natural weapons. You cannot, for obvious reasons,
>   be disarmed.

The damage for *Hand Weapons* (Corebook, p. 108)is *Strength Bonus* (SB). So each attack of this abomination does **1d10+6**. But regardless of which one it chooses to attack (bite or claws), it can only make one attack per round.